# Javafx window gets maximised with new stage if not so and gets restored if it is in maximised form

Tags: java, javafx

Could you please tell what I am making mistake here this code maximizes the current window if it is not so and viceversa.
This is done to refresh table view since refresh of table does not work after hiding PopOver of controlfx. It would have been better if you suggest an idea to refesh a table content after getting value from PopOver.

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private JFXButton btnViewMedicine;

@FXML
private JFXButton btnAdditional;

@FXML
private GridPane commGridMed;

@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;

@FXML
private Tab tabMedicine;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    btnViewMedicine.fire();
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
        @Override 
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
            if(newTab!=null) {
                if(newTab.equals (tabMedicine)) {            
                    btnViewMedicine.fire();
                }
            }
    }
    });
}

@FXML
public void viewMedicine(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    GridPane node = (GridPane) FXMLLoader
            .load(getClass().getResource(Constants.VIEW_MEDICINE));
    deleteNode();
    commGridMed.add(node, 0, 1);
}

@FXML
void viewAdditional(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    BorderPane node = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader
            .load(getClass().getResource(Constants.VIEW_ADDITIONAL));
    deleteNode();
    commGridMed.add(node, 0, 1);
}

public void viewAdditional() {
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    btnAdditional.fire();
}

public void viewMedicine() {
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    btnViewMedicine.fire();
}

private void deleteNode() {
    Set<Node> deleteNodes = new HashSet<>();
    for (Node child : commGridMed.getChildren()) {
        Integer row = GridPane.getRowIndex(child);
        Integer column = GridPane.getColumnIndex(child);
        if (row != null) {
            if (row.equals(1) && column.equals(0)) {
                deleteNodes.add(child);
            }
        }
    }
    commGridMed.getChildren().removeAll(deleteNodes);
}
```

}

```
public class ViewMethods{
public void refresh(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(Constants.HOME));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    HomeController controller = (HomeController) loader.getController();
    controller.viewAdditional();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = (Stage((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    //stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: So the problem is...?

Comment: As I said window get maximized when these codes are executed to get refreshed table values if it is in restored position . If it is in restored position it gets maximized.

Comment: @Sam You still haven't provided all the relevant code. Where is `commGridMed` defined? Can't you just copy and paste all the code? Is it too long?

Comment: I have edited it